# How to configure.py botan library to generate amalgamation files for both win32 and x64 build

Tags: botan

I'm trying to use the botan library in my vs2013 project. I would like to add  amagamated files to my project and be able to create my app in both win32 and x64 builds.

However, the amalgamated files (`botan_all.cpp`/`botan_all.h`/`botan_all_internal.h`) created by `configure.py` seem to be cpu-specific. Is there a configure.py option (like `--cpu=i386,x64`) to create files for both builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to create one amalgamation per build. So basically the workflow could be:

- Configure for 32 bit
- Copy botan_all.cpp/botan_all.h/botan_all_internal.h into a 32 bit sub-directory in your project
- Configure for 64 bit
- Copy botan_all.cpp/botan_all.h/botan_all_internal.h into a 64 bit sub-directory in your project